# Spark GroupBy operation performance Improvement

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a DataFrame like below around 1 billion records with approximately 100 columns.

```
+---------+---------+------+------+------+
|  Col1   |  Col2   | Col3 | col4 | col5 |
+---------+---------+------+------+------+
| Value 1 | Value 2 |  123 | 10.0 | sae  |
| Value 1 | Value 2 |  123 | 10.0 | ser  |
| Value 1 | Value 2 |  123 | 10.0 | wer  |
+---------+---------+------+------+------+
```

I have to apply groupBy operation on 5 columns out of 100 columns like below.

```
df.groupBy("col1").count()
df.groupBy("col2").count()
df.groupBy("col3").count()
df.groupBy("col4").count()
df.groupBy("col5").count()
```

As it is an expensive operation with too much shuffling it's taking more time. For applying groupBy operations for 5 times itself, it is taking more time.

But in my case I have to apply this 5 groupBy operations for every Filter.
like If there are 5 filters i have to apply groupBy operations by 5*5 time's

I am looking for a solution to resolve this issue with caching the whole data with partitions of those 5 columns. I'm thinking if we do the partitions the data will be local to that executor (Too much shuffle wont happen).

CodeWise Flow will be:

```
val df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("file://location")

val 1stdf = df.filter("$col1" == "a")
df.groupBy("col1").count()
df.groupBy("col2").count()
df.groupBy("col3").count()
df.groupBy("col4").count()
df.groupBy("col5").count()

val 2nddf = df.filter("$col2" == "abc")
df.groupBy("col1").count()
df.groupBy("col2").count()
df.groupBy("col3").count()
df.groupBy("col4").count()
df.groupBy("col5").count()

val 3rddf = df.filter("$col3" == "abdc")
df.groupBy("col1").count()
df.groupBy("col2").count()
df.groupBy("col3").count()
df.groupBy("col4").count()
df.groupBy("col5").count()
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code so we can see more of what you mean by 5 filters 5 group bys. Also where is the data coming from are these ORC tables from a spark sql statment?

Comment: I have updated the query

Comment: have you tried `df.agg(countDistinct("col1"), coundDistinct("cols2"), ...)` ?

Comment: I have tried df.agg(countDistinct("col1"), coundDistinct("cols2"), ...), but that is not suitable for my case. It gives only the distinct values count. But I want what is the distinct value and its count.